# How to generate urls in django

Tags: python, django, url, django-urls

In Django's template language, you can use `{% url [viewname] [args] %}` to generate a URL to a specific view with parameters. How can you programatically do the same in Python code?

What I need is to create a list of menu items where each item has name, URL, and an active flag  (whether it's the current page or not). This is because it will be a lot cleaner to do this in Python than the template language.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you need to use something similar to the `{% url %}` template tag in your code, Django provides the `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse()`. The `reverse` function has the following signature:

```
reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/

At the time of this edit the import is `django.urls import reverse`

Answer (score 11):

I'm using two different approaches in my `models.py`. The first is the `permalink` decorator:

```
from django.db.models import permalink

def get_absolute_url(self): 
    """Construct the absolute URL for this Item."""
    return ('project.app.views.view_name', [str(self.id)])
get_absolute_url = permalink(get_absolute_url)
```

You can also call `reverse` directly:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def get_absolute_url(self): 
    """Construct the absolute URL for this Item."""
    return reverse('project.app.views.view_name', None, [str(self.id)])
```

Comment: Is this the same as using the decorator?
@models.permalink

Answer (score 6):

For Python3 and Django 2:

```
from django.urls import reverse

url = reverse('my_app:endpoint', kwargs={'arg1': arg_1})
```

Answer (score 4):

Be aware that using `reverse()` requires that your urlconf module is 100% error free and can be processed - iow no `ViewDoesNotExist` errors or so, or you get the dreaded `NoReverseMatch` exception (errors in templates usually fail silently resulting in `None`).